# Two select statement in a query .dbf

Tags: sql, .net, dbf, oledbdataadapter

Can I do two select statement in different table in one query in OleDbCommand? I'm reading a .dbf files and I want to fill my dataset on it.

```
SELECT * FROM BILLHEAD SELECT * FROM BILLDETA
```

I'm getting an error

```
Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Here's my code :

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    oLoadDb("SELECT * FROM BILLHEAD " & vbCrLf & " SELECT * FROM BILLDETA")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = oDs.Tables(0).DefaultView 
    DataGridView2.DataSource = oDs.Tables(1).DefaultView

End Sub

Dim oDs As DataSet
Private Function oLoadDb(ByRef dbf_file As String)
    Try
        Dim FilePath As String = "D:\DBF"
        Dim SQLstr As String = dbf_file
        Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
        " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password="

        Try

            Dim DBFConn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
            DBFConn.Open()

            Dim DBFCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, DBFConn)
            Dim DBFDataReader As OleDbDataReader = DBFCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

            Dim daData As OleDbDataAdapter
            daData = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr, DBFConn)
            oDs = New DataSet

            daData.Fill(oDs)
            DBFConn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If both tables having the same data structure you can do

```
SELECT * FROM BILLHEAD 
UNION
SELECT * FROM BILLDETA
```

to get all data from the tables

Comment: I don't want to use UNION ALL, because I have to datagridview and I want to bind them separately. For example :    DataGridView1.DataSource = oDs.Tables(0).DefaultView 
    DataGridView2.DataSource = oDs.Tables(1).DefaultView

Comment: you cant get two results back - there for it is not possible to pass both statements.

Answer (score 0):

try below,batch execution

`oLoadDb("SELECT * FROM BILLHEAD SELECT * FROM BILLDETA")`

Comment: I'm getting error : Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: are both of your table hold same columns(name and types)?

Comment: The same error in my post. Systax error in FROM clause. Anyway, I've already accept that it can't be done. So what I did is like this     oLoadDb("SELECT * FROM BILLHEAD")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = oDs.Tables(0).DefaultView
oLoadDb("SELECT * FROM BILLDETA") 
    DataGridView2.DataSource = oDs.Tables(0).DefaultView